# Rails 6.1 development environment not printing query trigger code line with verbose active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I have both lines:

```
  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
  ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
```

in my `config/environments/development/rb`

But in my development log the sql queries are logged like:

```
2022-08-10 08:35:18.536410 D [74:puma srv tp 004] (0.006ms) ActiveRecord -- Model Load -- { :sql => "SELECT ....", :binds => { .... }, :allocations => 1, :cached => true }
```

I have an N+1 queries issue to fix, but the information about which line in the code triggered the query is missing, so this is not helping me much.

I tried also using [active-record-query-trace](https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace) gem, with configuration:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ActiveRecordQueryTrace.enabled = true
  ActiveRecordQueryTrace.level = :full
  ActiveRecordQueryTrace.colorize = true           # No colorization (default)
  ActiveRecordQueryTrace.colorize = :light_purple
  # Optional: other gem config options go here
end
```

but I see no changes at all in how queries are logged.

How can I enable the logging of the line triggering the query?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your development.rb file, I am guessing your logging is not set to DEBUG possibly.  Post that file and I might be able to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the reference point that made a DB query I used to use a gem called Marginalia.  I use it in Rails 6 and it does exactaly what you are looking for.

From what I am reading Rails 7 includes this feature as a native feature (which is quite awesome I might add).

I found a link that talks about this:
[Rails 7 includes Marginalia](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/09/15/rails-maginalia-query-logs.html)

Their example says:

```
# config/application.rb

module Saeloun
  class Application < Rails::Application
     config.active_record.query_log_tags_enabled = true
  end
end
```